# Java class in a parameter?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

Im new to programming but im not understanding this example:

```
public class Car {  
   public String name;  

   public String getName(Car name) { 
      return name;    
   }
}
```

the **Car name** im not understanding, i usually write

```
public String getName(String name){//code here}
```

Comment: Are you going to write all your code using just `Strings`? Sounds like you'll be creating a lot of boring programs. Besides, both the methods are missing a return type, so what you have there is a syntax error.

Comment: The example isn't legal code, as it is missing a return type. However, it is perfectly legal to name your variables as you wish and to use types of `Object`(s) that are not `String`(s).

Comment: Thank you both for answering, and yea the thing that im not understanding is when should i use primitive types like String,int,.. and when should i use types of Object(S)

Comment: `String` is not a primitive type, it's an object.

Comment: You pick which type of Object you want to use based on what you want to do with it.  If you want to represent a bit of text, use a `String`, if you want to represent a logical representation of a car, then you write a `Car` class and use it.

Comment: just to clear everything, the class Car is also an object?

Comment: A `class` is the definition of your fields and methods, whereas an `Object` is the instance of a `class`. So `Car` is your `class`, but when you instantiate it using `Car car = new Car()`, the instance `car` would be your `Object`.

Comment: The [Java lesson on Object-oriented programming](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/) may be useful to conceptualize some of this a little bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to fix your code has many possibilities. I can show you one to get you started:

```
public class Car {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String inputName) {
        this.name = inputName;
    }
}
```

Noticed I made the variable `private` instead of `public`, it is a common convention called "encapsulation".

You have a "getter" `getName()` to get the variable `name`, you also have a "setter" called `setName(String inputName)`, which takes an argument of `inputName` and assign the `name` to the private variable `name`.

Answer (score 1):

*public String getName is a method*, and **Car name** is argument, this method works when you invoke this method using Car class type argument.

*public String getName(String name)* this method has String as argument.
For more information [LINK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)